# Is there a way to build a mean of rows within a data.frame?

Tags: r

I need to run a t-test. I would like to check two different samples (which don't have the same number of participants) on the same question.

R tells me that arguments must have the same length. Can I somehow reduce the larger sample (200 observations) to the number of arguments of the smaller sample (28 observations) without loosing data?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `t.test(rnorm(200), rnorm(28), paired = FALSE)` works. Can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: This appears to be a question posted before reading the help page `?t.test`. When you do this, please pay attention to the Arguments section. Reading the help pages for functions is a great way to avoid being lost.

Comment: No. If you have a vector of length 200, you can not reduce its length to 28 without losing data. But that's fine because two sample t-tests don't require the two vectors to be the same length.